# ModalPopupExtender Hiding Behind IFrame

Tags: asp.net

I am using an Ajax ModalPopupExtender, but when it is activated it hides behind an IFrame on my web page. If I remove the IFrame then the ModalPopupExtender is top most. Any ideas? I've seen some other posts but they didn't help. I am using ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers, or just certain ones?  Can you use Firebug or similar tool to check the z-axis of the iframe and modalPopupExtender element?

Comment: Interestingly if set the src to another web page or image then it works fine. I was actually displaying .mht file, which in turn hid the popup.

Comment: I've got the modalpopupextender working nice but I have appox. 5 different dialogs. Do I put them all on the same page? That seems like the only way to accoplish this. It would be nice to have them on a separate page to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-Index property on Modalpopup or iframe. The higher the index is the top it will come...make you iframe z-index like -99.

this should work it.